# How do I Seq.collect with an async transform function?

Tags: f#, async-await

Suppose I have two `async` functions:

- `fetchCategories` fetches a list of product categories (`string List`)
- `fetchProductsForCategory` fetches a list of products for a given category (`string List`)

I would like to write a function `fetchProducts` that fetches all products for all categories. The result should be a list of tuples (`string * string List`).

However, I am not sure now to fit `async` and `Seq.collect` together.

Here is my attempt, which should hopefully make the intent clear:

```
let fetchProducts () = async {
  let! categories = fetchCategories ()
  return categories
    |> Seq.collect (fun c -> async {
      let! products = fetchProductsForCategory c
      return products
        |> Seq.map fun p -> (c, p)
    })
    |> Seq.toList
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to achieve what you're after is to simply run all `fetchProductsForCategory` in succession, one after another, then concatenate their results. In order to wait for the previous execution to finish before running the next one, use `Async.RunSynchronously`:

```
let fetchProducts () = async {
  let! categories = fetchCategories ()
  return categories
    |> Seq.collect (fun c ->
      fetchProductsForCategory c 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously          
        |> Seq.map (fun p -> (c, p))
    )
    |> Seq.toList
}
```

(note, by the way, that your code produces not `Seq<string * string list>`, which you say you expect, but `Seq<string * string>` - each product with its category; but that's beside the point)

However, this approach has a distinct disadvantage of wasting valuable time. Executions of `fetchProductsForCategory` could run in parallel, thus achieving better performance.

And lo: there is an app for that. The [`Async.Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.parallel%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) function takes a sequence of async computations, runs them all in parallel, and returns their results as an array:

```
let fetchProducts () = async {
  let! categories = fetchCategories ()
  let! products = categories 
                   |> Seq.map fetchProductsForCategory 
                   |> Async.Parallel

  Seq.zip categories products
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `Seq.zip` is correct here.  The original code returned a tuple of the category and product for all the products in a given category.  This will return tuples of categories and products based on their order in the sequence, rather than to which category the product belongs.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach This is precisely what the OP asked for, even though their own code doesn't do it. I even noted this discrepancy in the middle of my answer.

Comment: I think it's still different, no?  `Seq.zip ["A"; "B"; "C"] ["apple"; "apricot"; "banana"]` will give `[("A", "apple"); ("B", "apricot"); ("C", "banana")]`, but I think the original code gives `[("A", "apple"); ("A", "apricot"); ("B", "banana")]`.

Comment: Basically, what I'm suggesting is that instead of `Seq.zip`, your `Seq.map` would be `Seq.map (fun c -> async.Bind(fetchProductsForCategory c, (fun p -> c,p) >> async.Return))`

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach `fetchProductsForCategory` returns a sequence, not a single value.

Comment: I'm not too fussed about the exact output... any inconsistencies are due to my unfamiliarity with F# syntax. The main question was about unwrapping the async context, which this answers. Cheers!